# Cocoa tutorial suggestions

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am learning Cocoa programming for Mac apps. Where can I find a good video tutorial or class online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://cocoadevcentral.com/
http://www.cocoacast.com/
http://www.johncmurphy.com/tutorials.aspx?CategoryID=2

Also try iTunes U or podcast search. I'm sure youtube has many videos on this subject as well.

Comment: +1 for cocoadevcentral, great resource. The other 2 are probably good as well, but I've not run across them.